# Mysql Query issue of comparing two table list value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is user and second one is contact

in user table,

```
userId   phone
1        +91A12345678
2        +91A98765432
3        +1A1234
4        +91A2222
```

and in contact table,

```
 userId    contactNumber
    6         12345678
    7         +112345
    8         +912222
```

now i want to remove A from phone column of user table and compare with contactNumber of contact table.

and I want this type of output

```
userId     ContactNumber
6          12345678
8          +912222
```

Anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are not able to get expected result of your choice. You can try union all functions. Please check query.

```
select c.*
from contact_master c
join user_details u on replace(u.mobile, 'A', '') = c.contactNumber

union all

SELECT c.*
FROM contact_master c
INNER JOIN user_details u
    ON REPLACE(u.mobile, 'A', '') REGEXP c.contactNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
INNER JOIN contact c
    ON REPLACE(u.phone, 'A', '') REGEXP c.contactNumber;
```